# Multiple slideshow in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a slideshow to fit correctly in a table.  I am new to jquery. I want to fit it within cells of the table. I have tried to adjust the slideshow "li" attribute but can't get it to work. Please help me to achieve this. Here is my code,

**Code:**
In head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slideshow.js"></script>

<style>
    .slideshow {
        position: relative;
    }

        .slideshow li {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 310px;
            height: 86px;
            display: table-cell;
            list-style: none;
        }

            .slideshow li:first-child {
                display: block;
            }

    .slideshow-2 {
        top: 0px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    document.documentElement.className += 'js';
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.slideshow').slideshow({ timeout: 2000, speed: 1000 });
    });    
</script>
```

In body section

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="660">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="320">
        <ul class="slideshow">
            <li><img src="images/00accord.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/00grandprix.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/00mercedes.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/01cadillac.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/01century.jpg" height="86" width="310" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/01ptcruiser.jpg" height="86" width="310" /></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="320">
        <ul class="slideshow slideshow-2">
            <li><img src="images/01ram.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/02mazda.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/03nissan.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/03stratus.jpg" height="86" width="310"></li>
            <li><img src="images/03stratusrt.jpg" height="86" width="310" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/05sebring.jpg" height="86" width="310" /></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is the minimal example

Comment: How do I create minimal example

Comment: Read the link in my last comment.

Comment: sushain97 I have edited my post for just the code that I am having a problem with.